# SetEnv or PassEnv Variables for cgi bin perl script

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

Have an apache project and a perl script in cgi-bin that needs to read from env variables.

Using `PassEnv` or `SetEnv` in the apache config the variables don't show up when looping through the env variables in perl

`foreach $key (sort keys(%ENV)) {
  print "$key = $ENV{$key}<p>";
}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me. It might help to show your Apache config.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, Apache's [suexec](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/suexec.html) wrapper clears all environment variables that don't appear on its whitelist. Generally speaking, this whitelist only includes variables that are part of the CGI interface: `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, `REQUEST_METHOD`, `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, *etc*, as well as any variable starting with `HTTP_` (from HTTP headers).

Unfortunately, this makes `SetEnv` basically useless when suexec is enabled. This is a known limitation, but is difficult to solve without introducing potential security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Where does the OP say he's using suexec? SetEnv works fine without it.

Comment: It's a best guess. suexec is on by default in many web server configurations, and it neatly explains why environment variables would be missing.